# Debugging Django admin panel bug

Tags: python, django, debugging, django-models

When I navigate to the admin interface for a particular model (the whole-table view), and simply hit 'Save', this error was popping up on the usual red banner:

```
Please correct the errors below.
```

Needless to say I couldn't actually make edits from this view, until I experimented and fixed it.

Here's my class:

```
 class RoleMapping(models.Model):
     MIN_LENGTH, MAX_LENGTH = 3, 40
     role_name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=MAX_LENGTH, validators = [
         MinLengthValidator(MIN_LENGTH, "Field length should be greater than {}".format(MIN_LENGTH))
     ])
     role_type = models.ForeignKey(RoleType, null=True, blank=True )
```

Here's the admin interface model. But, flipping around some of the editable fields seems to have made things work.

```
 class RoleMapping(admin.ModelAdmin):
     model = RoleMapping
     list_display = ('role_name', 'role_type',)
     #list_editable = ('role_name', 'role_type',) # This fails
     #list_editable = ('role_name',) # This fails
     list_editable = ('role_type',) # This works?!
```

I can get it working, pretty easily, by keeping role_type as the only editable type. However, I only found this out after a bit of trial and error. I'm wondering:

1. What's the django way of debugging these sorts of admin-panel-ORM
   issues in the future
2. Why might it have been failing in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

According to [the Django admin docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_editable):

> Note: `list_editable` interacts with a couple of other options in
>   particular ways; you should note the following rules:
>
> - Any field in `list_editable` must also be in `list_display`. You can’t edit a field that’s not displayed!
> - The same field can’t be listed in both `list_editable` and    `list_display_links` – a field can’t be both a form and a link.
>
> You’ll get a validation error if either of these rules are broken.

My guess is that you are violating the second point and that `role_name` is by default the sole member of `list_display_links`.

To test this, set `list_display_links = None` or make another field and add it to `list_display` and `list_display_links`.

**Edit:**

I suspect that the following will give you what you want. I've simply added `id` as the first element of `list_display`. Behind the scenes, this adds `id` instead of `role_name` to `list_display_links`, which frees up `role_name` to be allowed in `list_editable`.

```
class RoleMapping(admin.ModelAdmin):
     model = RoleMapping
     list_display = ('id', 'role_name', 'role_type',)
     list_editable = ('role_name', 'role_type',)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link! I'm not sure this applies in my situation - I don't have any list_display_links around.

Comment: @mallyvai When you go to the admin page for `RoleMapping`, do you click on the `role_name` to go to the detail for a specific record? If so, that means `role_name` is in the `list_display_links` tuple (by default).

Comment: @mallyvai See the edit in my answer. I've added code for the `RoleMapping` admin that I believe will solve your problem.